# Assembly language bootloader code problem

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I'm trying to understand a bootloader contents, but facing some troubles in below given code portion, please help. I am mentioning comments here, this will help you, why we are using 07C0h, is it a fix location or arbitrary then what is 544 in second line.

```
Bootloader_start:    
mov ax, 07C0h        ;set up 4k of stack space above buffer
add ax, 544 ;8k buffer = 512 paragraphs + 32 paragraphs 
                      ;(loader) 

cli                  ;disable interrupts while changing stack
mov ss, ax 
mov sp, 4096
sti                  ;restore interrupts

mov ax, 07C0h ;set data segment to where we are loaded
mov ds, ax

cmp dl, 0
je no_change
mov [bootdev], dl    ;save boot device number   
mov ah, 8                 ;get drive parameters
int 13h
jc fatal_disk_error
and cx, 3fh              ;maximum sector number 
mov [SectorsPerTrack], cx  ;Sector numbers start at 1
movzx dx, dh        ;maximum head number
add dx, 1.             ;head number starts at 0 - add 1 for total
mov [Sides], dx
```

......continues

Comment: This is both too broad and missing the context that would make more of this make more sense.  Why would anyone write `mov ax, imm16` / `add ax, imm16` instead of just `mov ax, 07c0h + 544`?  And if you're going to use 386 instructions like `movzx`, why work around the early-stepping-8086 bug where `mov ss, reg` didn't disable interrupts until the end of the next instruction?

Comment: Without any specific questions, an answer would have to be huge to go into enough detail for every instruction, and every group of instructions at a higher level, and the BIOS call...  Posting something you understand nothing about and asking SO to write you a tutorial is not how we do things around here.

Comment: Look up literally anything about bootloaders and it will explain that the ABI is for the BIOS to load the MBR to linear address `7C00h`, which is why boot sectors typically use `org 7c00h` and set DS=0, or `org 0` and set DS=`07C0h`.  (Unfortunately that's all you can trust; some BIOSes violate the written standard by setting CS:IP to the right linear address but with not the documented seg:off.)

Comment: mov ax, 07C0h   
add ax, 288         ; (512 + 4096) / 16 = 288
mov ss, ax                                                               This puts the start of the stack segment (ss) at segment number 07C0h + 288. The bootloader is loaded at the start of segment number 07C0h. The size of a bootloader is 512 bytes and each segment is 16 bytes. This means that the stack segments starts 4096 bytes after the end of the bootloader.

Comment: Hi Peter thanks for your help. I found some old lines in stack overflow as I have given, please help me understand why we are putting value 288 in AX

Comment: The code in the question doesn't put 288 in AX, IDK what you're talking about.  If I have this right, it sets up the stack so SS:0 is 544 * 16 bytes beyond the start of the 512-byte MBR that's loaded at linear address `0x7C00`.  Or 8kiB past the end like the comments show.  Then setting SP=4096 leaves 4kiB of stack space before stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Bootloader_start:    
> mov ax, 07C0h   ;set up 4k of stack space above buffer
> add ax, 544     ;8k buffer = 512 paragraphs + 32 paragraphs (loader) 
>
> cli             ;disable interrupts while changing stack
> mov ss, ax 
> mov sp, 4096
> sti             ;restore interrupts
>
> mov ax, 07C0h   ;set data segment to where we are loaded
> mov ds, ax
> ```

First the obvious optimization that would have avoided the right criticism by Peter about not using the assembly-time addition:

```
Bootloader_start:    
mov ax, 07C0h  ;set up 4k of stack space above buffer
MOV DS, AX
add ax, 544    ;8k buffer = 512 paragraphs + 32 paragraphs (loader) 
cli            ;disable interrupts while changing stack
mov ss, ax 
mov sp, 4096
sti            ;restore interrupts
```

Then why the 544?

The author wants to have an 8192 byte buffer **plus** a 4096 byte stack directly above the bootloader which sits in memory at linear address 7C00h.

Do the math knowing that linear address 7C00h is paragraph 07C0h:

```
              Paragraph
              ---------
                07C0h    Bootloader 512 bytes ==  32 paragraphs (20h)
07C0h + 0020h = 07E0h    Buffer    8192 bytes == 512 paragraphs (200h)
07E0h + 0200h = 09E0h    Stack     4096 bytes
                                                 ---
                                                 544
```

The bottom of the stack is at paragraph `09E0h` which is `07C0h + (32 + 512)` or `07C0h + 544`.
The stackpointer `SP` is then set at offset 4096 so we have a full `SS:SP`.